# Convert variable from little endian to big endian

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hex, byte

Working in Bash
I have a hex variable that I must convert from little endian to big endian
I am new to the entire concept of this and only learned about this about 20 minutes ago, so please bare with me.

My script determines a hex variable that undergoes a few changes: decimal, signed 2's complement, and division by 8.

Before everything though it must go through little endian to big endian conversion (I may be confusing the two but my example below should clarify)

EXAMPLE:

1. Hex Value: 0080
   After Conversion: 8000
2. Hex Value: 9800
   After Conversion: 0098
3. Hex Value: 1234
   After Conversion: 3412

I believe that this is a 16 bit hex variable as it is always 4 digits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

To swap the endianness of a 16-bit value, you need to exchange the positions of the two bytes. That can be deconstructed into isolating the bytes from the word, moving them to another bit position within the word, and combining them back to a single word.

To isolate some bits, use a binary *and*, `&`. You have `x & 0 = 0` and `x & 1 = x`, in effect `1` bits in one operand giving the bits from the other operand. So, e.g. `0xab & 0x0f = 0x0b` gives the low four bits.

To move them around, use a shift, `<<` or `>>`. E.g. `0x0f << 4 = 0xf0`.

To combine the values, use a binary *or*, `|`. E.g. `0x30 | 0x07 = 0x37`.

Combined, to byte-swap `x` to `y`:

```
l = x & 0x00ff             # isolate low byte
h = x & 0xff00             # isolate high byte
y = (l << 8) | (h >> 8)    # move and combine
```

The operators for those operations is the same in many programming languages, they're inherited from C. That includes the shell, but there, you'll have to put the expression inside an arithmetic expansion, so `$(( ... ))`. (That is if you want to do something like this in the shell anyway, it's probably not the best of tools for something like this.)